# Flutter Simple Animations: The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'

Tags: android, flutter, dart

So I'm using the `simple_animations: ^5.0.2` package but the project that I am trying to run was made on an older version of simple animations, so I don't have much knowledge about this package but I'm trying to mimic what the old version did:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:simple_animations/simple_animations.dart';

class FadeAnimation extends StatelessWidget {
  final double delay;
  final Widget child;

  FadeAnimation(this.delay, this.child);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final tween = MovieTween();

    tween.tween('opacity', Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0), duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    tween.tween('translateY', Tween(begin: -30.0, end: 0.0), duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.easeOut);

    return PlayAnimationBuilder(
      delay: Duration(milliseconds: (500 * delay).round()),
      duration: tween.duration,
      tween: tween,
      child: child,
      builder: (context, movie, child) => Opacity(
        opacity: child['opacity'], // The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'. Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').
        child: Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(0, child["translateY"]), child: child), // The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'. Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I get the errors on lines 23 and 25 that basically state the same thing, "The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'. Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!')." And I don't know how to fix this please help.

### Old Version

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:simple_animations/simple_animations.dart';

class FadeAnimation extends StatelessWidget {
  final double delay;
  final Widget child;

  FadeAnimation(this.delay, this.child);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final tween = MultiTrackTween([
      Track("opacity").add(Duration(milliseconds: 500), Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0)),
      Track("translateY").add(
        Duration(milliseconds: 500), Tween(begin: -30.0, end: 0.0),
        curve: Curves.easeOut)
    ]);

    return ControlledAnimation(
      delay: Duration(milliseconds: (500 * delay).round()),
      duration: tween.duration,
      tween: tween,
      child: child,
      builderWithChild: (context, child, animation) => Opacity(
        opacity: animation["opacity"],
        child: Transform.translate(
          offset: Offset(0, animation["translateY"]), 
          child: child
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `child['opacity']` to do? Why would it even compile?

Answer (score 0):

In general, it means you should put null check operator before the **[**. So you'd use:

- **?** if the parameter/variable you are assigning the value to(in your case it's **code**), can be null or
- **!** if the parameter/variable you are assigning the value to, can't be null. In this case, you also have to make sure it's not null.

Example: *child?['opacity']* or *child!['opacity']*

If you are using vscode or android studio you can use "quick fix" action in similar cases to solve the problem faster.